# What is the relationship between Cyclotomic Field Extensions and Circles?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

In the following paper, http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf,
the author writes,

"For any field K, an extension of the form K(ζ), where ζ is a root of unity, is called a cyclotomic extension of K. The term cyclotomic means “circle-dividing,” which comes from the fact that the nth roots of unity in C divide a circle into n arcs of equal length."

Does this mean that the Complex Numbers form a Cyclotomic Field Extension of the Reals where n = 4? I was thinking this because 1,-1,i,-i would then divide the unit circle into 4 arcs of equal length.

I may, however, be misinterpreting the meaning of the term "nth roots of unity", so any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.